# MySQL trigger update last inserted row

Tags: mysql, triggers, row

I have this table (SystemEvents):

```
id       ipv4        ipnumber
 1       1.2.3.4      
 2       3.4.5.6
```

I need an AFTER INSERT trigger which will update the last row of this table.

Something like the following

```
UPDATE SystemEvents 
SET ipnumber=INET_ATON(NEW.ipv4)
WHERE id=NEW.id
```

Is this correct?

Although the syntax seems ok, I cannot make it work!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please Show **AFTER INSERT Trigger**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `BEFORE INSERT` works

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER `some_name` BEFORE INSERT ON SystemEvents
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   SET NEW.ipnumber = INET_ATON(NEW.ipv4);
END
| 
delimiter ;
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c98925/1)

Comment: I got this: ERROR 1362: Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

Comment: not working either. Everything is stuck, no new rows inserted

Comment: Yeap! using before insert trigger instead of after insert is the key.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
UPDATE SystemEvents 
SET ipnumber=INET_ATON(NEW.ipv4)
WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM SystemEvents WHERE id < NEW.id);
```